# JavaScript Exception Is Lost In Promise Chain

Tags: javascript, android, promise

I am new to JavaScript promises and I am trying to implement them into some PhoneGap code on an Android device.  I want to log exceptions and it looks like exceptions are swallowed somewhere.  See the sample code below.  The exception thrown due to the call to the non-existent function "thiswillfail" does not show anywhere.  I commented out the irrelevant code and added code to force the AddRecord promise to be called. The code checks if a record exists and, if not, return the AddRecord promise which is the error is.  I am not using any 3rd party libraries.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: If I add another promise in the chain "DoSomethingWithRecord", this promise is called when the expectation is to skip to the catch.

```
function TestPromiseExceptionHandling() {
var record = null;
var CheckForRecord = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //getData(
        //    function (data) {
        var data = "";
        if (data != "") {
            //record = new Record(data);
            record = "existed";
            resolve();
        }
        else return AddRecord();
        //    },
        //    function (err) {
        //        reject(new Error("An error occurred retrieving data, msg=" + err.message));
        //    });
    });
};
var AddRecord = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        thiswillfail();
        //add record
        var success = true;
        record = "new";
        if (success) resolve();
        else reject(new Error("add record failed"));
    });
};
var DoSomthingWithRecord = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        alert(record);
        resolve();
    });
};


try {
    CheckForRecord()
        .then(DoSomthingWithRecord())
        .catch(function (err) { alert(err.message);})
        .then(function () { alert("done"); });
} catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return from the promise constructor, when you do:

```
else return AddRecord();
```

Nothing will wait for AddRecord, instead, you want to resolve with AddRecord which will wait for it before resolving the promise:

```
else resolve(AddRecord());
```

However, if this is your code you can just `return AddRecord()` instead of using the promise constructor anyway. The promise constructor (new Promise) is mostly useful for *converting non-promise APIs to promises* and aren't supposed to be used with already promisified APIs. Use `then`s instead.

Comment: Also, `thisWillFail` has to throw to fail, promises only know of failure via throw/return values or via reject/resolve in the promise constructor (which again - you probably shouldn't use here)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. Your suggestion seems to fix the issue of the exception being swallowed but I'm still not seeing the expected behavior. I intentionally added the line thisWillFail (which does not exist) to cause an exception. The expected behavior was that all other promises in the chain would be skipped, the exception would be caught in .catch and alert("done") should execute. The exception is now caught but it is caught in the try/catch, not in .catch.  Additionally, DoSomethingWithRecord still executes and alert("done") does not.  Very strange.

Comment: I tried this exact test using q.js and everything works as expected. The exception is caught in .catch, DoSomethingWithRecord doesn't execute and I get the alert.  I'm not sure if it's something with how I'm trying to implement native promises or a limitation but since I have it working with Q, I'm going to stick with that.